# Unable to Create MVC 4 Web API or any Web Project with VS 2012 or VS 2013 Preview

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, windows-7, .net-4.0, iis-7.5, visual-studio-2013

I am getting an error while trying to add a new project using VS 2013 Preview On Windows 7 Machine. I have also tried a web forms project but same error. so looks like i haven't configured something properly, even though i have tried almost everything:

```
Creation of the virtual directory "http://localhost:50161/ failed with the error:
Filename:redirection.config
Error: Cannot read configuration file
```

Can anyone please help?

This is how my project file looks like for this web api project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
<Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
<Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
<ProductVersion>
</ProductVersion>
<SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
<ProjectGuid>{18A6F9D4-D8BF-4137-A766-5859742DD230}</ProjectGuid>
<ProjectTypeGuids>{E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
<OutputType>Library</OutputType>
<AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
<RootNamespace>MVC4ServiceBook.Web.Api</RootNamespace>
<AssemblyName>MVC4ServiceBook.Web.Api</AssemblyName>
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
<MvcBuildViews>false</MvcBuildViews>
<UseIISExpress>True</UseIISExpress>
<IISExpressSSLPort />
<IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication />
<IISExpressWindowsAuthentication />
<IISExpressUseClassicPipelineMode />
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
<DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
<DebugType>full</DebugType>
<Optimize>false</Optimize>
<OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
<DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
<ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
<WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
<DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
<Optimize>true</Optimize>
<OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
<DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
<ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
<WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
<Reference Include="System" />
<Reference Include="System.Data" />
<Reference Include="System.Data.Entity" />
<Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
<Reference Include="System.Web.Entity" />
<Reference Include="System.Web.ApplicationServices" />
<Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" />
<Reference Include="System.Core" />
<Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
<Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
<Reference Include="System.Web" />
<Reference Include="System.Web.Abstractions" />
<Reference Include="System.Web.Routing" />
<Reference Include="System.Xml" />
<Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
<Reference Include="EntityFramework">
  <HintPath>..\..\lib\EntityFramework.5.0.0\lib\net40\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
  <HintPath>..\..\lib\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0.0\lib\net40\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
  <Reference Include="Microsoft.Web.Mvc.FixedDisplayModes, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
  <HintPath>..\..\lib\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.FixedDisplayModes.1.0.0\lib\net40\Microsoft.Web.Mvc.FixedDisplayModes.dll</HintPath>
 </Reference>
 <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json">
  <HintPath>..\..\lib\Newtonsoft.Json.4.5.11\lib\net40\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
 </Reference>
 <Reference Include="System.Net.Http">
  <Private>True</Private>
  <HintPath>..\..\lib\Microsoft.Net.Http.2.0.30506.0\lib\net40\System.Net.Http.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\..\lib\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.4.0.30506.0\lib\net40\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll</HintPath>
 </Reference>
 <Reference Include="System.Net.Http.WebRequest">
  <Private>True</Private>
  <HintPath>..\..\lib\Microsoft.Net.Http.2.0.30506.0\lib\net40\System.Net.Http.WebRequest.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
  <Reference Include="System.Web.Helpers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
  <HintPath>..\..\lib\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.2.0.30506.0\lib\net40\System.Web.Helpers.dll</HintPath>
   </Reference>
   <Reference Include="System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\..\lib\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.4.0.30506.0\lib\net40\System.Web.Http.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
  <Reference Include="System.Web.Http.WebHost, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\..\lib\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost.4.0.30506.0\lib\net40\System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
  <Reference Include="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
  <HintPath>..\..\lib\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.4.0.30506.0\lib\net40\System.Web.Mvc.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
  <Reference Include="System.Web.Optimization">
  <HintPath>..\..\lib\Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.1.0.0\lib\net40\System.Web.Optimization.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
  <Reference Include="System.Web.Providers">
  <HintPath>..\..\lib\Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core.1.2\lib\net40\System.Web.Providers.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
  <Reference Include="System.Web.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
  <HintPath>..\..\lib\Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.2.0.30506.0\lib\net40\System.Web.Razor.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
  <Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
  <HintPath>..\..\lib\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.2.0.30506.0\lib\net40\System.Web.WebPages.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
  <Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages.Deployment, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
  <HintPath>..\..\lib\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.2.0.30506.0\lib\net40\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll</HintPath>
   </Reference>
   <Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
  <HintPath>..\..\lib\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.2.0.30506.0\lib\net40\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Web.Http.Tracing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
   <HintPath>..\..\lib\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Tracing.4.0.30506\lib\net40\System.Web.Http.Tracing.dll</HintPath>
   </Reference>
   <Reference Include="System.Web.Http.OData, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
  <HintPath>..\..\lib\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData.4.0.30506\lib\net40\System.Web.Http.OData.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
  <Reference Include="Microsoft.Data.Edm, Version=5.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
  <HintPath>..\..\lib\Microsoft.Data.Edm.5.2.0\lib\net40\Microsoft.Data.Edm.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
  <Reference Include="Microsoft.Data.OData, Version=5.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
  <HintPath>..\..\lib\Microsoft.Data.OData.5.2.0\lib\net40\Microsoft.Data.OData.dll</HintPath>
   </Reference>
   <Reference Include="System.Spatial, Version=5.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
  <HintPath>..\..\lib\System.Spatial.5.2.0\lib\net40\System.Spatial.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="WebGrease">
  <Private>True</Private>
  <HintPath>..\..\lib\WebGrease.1.3.0\lib\WebGrease.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Antlr3.Runtime">
  <Private>True</Private>
  <HintPath>..\..\lib\WebGrease.1.3.0\lib\Antlr3.Runtime.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
 </ItemGroup>
 <ItemGroup>
<Compile Include="App_Start\BundleConfig.cs" />
<Compile Include="App_Start\FilterConfig.cs" />
<Compile Include="App_Start\RouteConfig.cs" />
<Compile Include="App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs" />
<Compile Include="Controllers\HomeController.cs" />
<Compile Include="Controllers\ValuesController.cs" />
<Compile Include="Global.asax.cs">
  <DependentUpon>Global.asax</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
 </ItemGroup>
 <ItemGroup>
<Content Include="favicon.ico" />
<Content Include="Global.asax" />
  <Content Include="Web.config" />
<Content Include="Web.Debug.config">
  <DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>
</Content>
<Content Include="Web.Release.config">
  <DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>
</Content>
<Content Include="Areas\HelpPage\Views\_ViewStart.cshtml" />
<Content Include="Content\Site.css" />
<Content Include="Images\accent.png" />
<Content Include="Images\bullet.png" />
<Content Include="Images\heroAccent.png" />
<Content Include="Images\orderedList0.png" />
<Content Include="Images\orderedList1.png" />
<Content Include="Images\orderedList2.png" />
<Content Include="Images\orderedList3.png" />
<Content Include="Images\orderedList4.png" />
<Content Include="Images\orderedList5.png" />
<Content Include="Images\orderedList6.png" />
<Content Include="Images\orderedList7.png" />
<Content Include="Images\orderedList8.png" />
<Content Include="Images\orderedList9.png" />
<Content Include="Scripts\_references.js" />
<Content Include="Views\Web.config" />
<Content Include="Views\_ViewStart.cshtml" />
<Content Include="Views\Home\Index.cshtml" />
<Content Include="Views\Shared\Error.cshtml" />
<Content Include="Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml" />
</ItemGroup>
 <ItemGroup>
<Folder Include="App_Data\" />
<Folder Include="Models\" />
 </ItemGroup>
 <PropertyGroup>
<VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
<VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
 </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
 <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="false" />
  <Target Name="MvcBuildViews" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(MvcBuildViews)'=='true'">
 <AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(WebProjectOutputDir)" />
 </Target>
 <ProjectExtensions>
 <VisualStudio>
  <FlavorProperties GUID="{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}">
    <WebProjectProperties>
      <UseIIS>False</UseIIS>
      <AutoAssignPort>True</AutoAssignPort>
      <DevelopmentServerPort>0</DevelopmentServerPort>
      <DevelopmentServerVPath>/</DevelopmentServerVPath>
      <IISUrl>
      </IISUrl>
      <NTLMAuthentication>False</NTLMAuthentication>
      <UseCustomServer>False</UseCustomServer>
      <CustomServerUrl>
      </CustomServerUrl>
      <SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>False</SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>
    </WebProjectProperties>
    </FlavorProperties>
    </VisualStudio>
    </ProjectExtensions>
   <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and    uncomment it. 
   Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
 <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
 </Target>
 <Target Name="AfterBuild">
 </Target> -->
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

I deleted the SQLExpress folder under MyDocuments, uninstalled IIS, reinstalled IIS and it recreated the SQLExpress folder with the redirection.config file in it this time (which wasn't there previously) and then i just gave read permissions to IIS_IUSRS user to read that file and the issue was gone.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem opening up a 2 year old project. My solutions was to delete (actually rename and delete later) the folder **C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache**